# Invalid credential Error while activating Coveo for Sitecore 5

Tags: coveo

So I am installing and configuring Coveo 5 for Sitecore, first time

There is a new activation interface, not just the dialog as before but now a whole page

I can't get past this error, the Coveo activation interface won't accept admin/b as good credentials, I've tried another admin account. There seems to be some error in it's ability to take the "Sitecore Credentials". Anybody seen this one?

http://daltile.sc/coveo/command-center/index.html#activation/

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You must also enter the domain, like "sitecore\admin".

This call is using IIS' credentials validation method, `Membership.ValidateUser`, which requires you to use the domain (unlike Sitecore's `AuthenticationManager`).

Our team has been made aware of this and might change it in the future, but as of now, please use the domain :)